# How to automate the compilation of all the data from different tab (same range) using QUERY in google sheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to combine all the data from different tab (`Exercise 1`, `Exercise 2`, `Exercise 3`) under the `Main` tab. I achieved that by using the `QUERY` function as shown in the screenshot above. However, there will be `Exercise 4`, `Exercise 5`,`...` in the future where the tabs have not been created. Once the tab for `Exercise 4`, `Exercise 5`,`...` have been created, I need to modified the `QUERY` function in the main tab.

I'm looking for a way to automate the `QUERY` function so that I'm not required to modify the `QUERY` function every time when I have an extra new tab. May I know is there any way that I can achieve this automation on `QUERY` function? If there is other method without using `QUERY` function and able to achieve the same goal, please let me know as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is the link for my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqmokrdbkvXQzx2WLSkfzR06aTA96NBfaP8pNTp1AqE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Option is to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to update your sheet `Main` using [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) or [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

### Sample Code:

```
function getsheetdata() {
  var range = 'A3:B';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var data=[];
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {

    
    //Logger.log(sheet.getName());
    if(sheet.getName()!="Main"){
      Logger.log(sheet.getName());
      var tmpData = sheet.getRange(range).getDisplayValues();
      var tmpData = tmpData.filter(rowData => {
        return (rowData[0]!="");
      });

      data.push(tmpData);
    }
  });

  data = data.flat();
  //Delete existing data in Main!A3:B
  ss.getSheetByName("Main").getRange("A3:B").clear();

  //Write to Main!A3:B
  ss.getSheetByName("Main").getRange(3,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Refresh Menu')
      .addItem('REFRESH MAIN', 'getsheetdata')
      .addToUi();
}
```

### What it does?

- Create a custom menu that will call the `getsheetdata()` when clicked
- In `getsheetdata()`:

1. Define the `range` of the data to be collected from all the existing sheets (excluding the main sheet)
2. Get all sheets available in the spreadsheet using [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets). Loop each sheets (excluding the main sheet) and get the value of the `range` defined in step1.
3. Filter the 2-d array values returned by [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues), by checking column 1 (array index 0) which should be not empty/null. Append the filtered data into an array `data` using `array.push()`
4. Change the `data` from 3-d array to 2-d array using `array.flat()`
5. Delete existing data in `Main!A3:B`. Then write the `data` collected.

### (OPTIONAL)

You can set a Time-driven trigger to execute  `getsheetdata()` automatically every minute.

[image]

[image]

### Output:

**(Update data using time-driven trigger every 1-minute)**

[image]

**(Update data using custom menu)**

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most elegant solution, but it will allow you to set up your query  with future ranges:

```
=QUERY({
if(E3<>"",indirect(E3),{"",""});
if(E4<>"",indirect(E4),{"",""});
if(E5<>"",indirect(E5),{"",""});
if(E6<>"",indirect(E6),{"",""});
if(E7<>"",indirect(E7),{"",""})
}, "Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

The example values in `E3:E7` could go on a config sheet, but for ease, I've put them on the Main sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use scripts you can pre-program future sheets like:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR('Exercise 1'!A3:B, {"",""});
 IFERROR('Exercise 2'!A3:B, {"",""});
 IFERROR('Exercise 3'!A3:B, {"",""});
 IFERROR('Exercise 4'!A3:B, {"",""});
 IFERROR('Exercise 5'!A3:B, {"",""});
 IFERROR('Exercise 6'!A3:B, {"",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

this way as soon as they will be created the query will read them